# html2canvas too many base64 image request in network

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to take screenshot in a section of my page. Why does it creates a lot of request?

[image]

Anyone knows what this request are? It's making my developers tool unresponsive due to having too many requests.

Here's the code.

```
html2canvas($('#itemList')).then(function(canvas) {
                var main_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var element = $('#itemList').find('.list-item');

                var width = parseInt(element.css('width'));
                var height = parseInt(element.css('height'));
                var margin = parseInt(element.css('marginTop'));
                var box_shadow = element.css('box-shadow');
                var radiusTopLeft = element.css('borderTopLeftRadius');
                var radiusTopRight = element.css('borderTopRightRadius');
                var radiusBottomLeft = element.css('borderBottomLeftRadius');
                var radiusBottomRight = element.css('borderBottomRightRadius');
                var border = 0;

                main_canvas.width = width;
                main_canvas.height = height;

                var ctx = main_canvas.getContext('2d');

                ctx.drawImage(canvas, margin, margin, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

                var dataURL = main_canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.5);

               $('#screenshot').attr('src', dataURL);
            });
```

Here's a sample fiddle that also generates a data uri and involved the network

http://jsfiddle.net/Lybrzztw/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls html2canvas?

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: can you also show the html on which it is called?

Comment: html is too big to add here. It's around 1000+ lines of code. Anyway do you know what those requests are?

Comment: Yes, html2canvas has to render some of your documents to images first (, which may produce those dataURL requests. The odd thing is that Chrome now reports them in Network panel... There is no network involved since it's data URI, so I don't why it does so... Also, it seems odd html2canvas creates png dataURL while it could just reuse the canvas it used to produce those. That's why it would be inetersting if you could provide an [MCVE] : remove as much elements you can in your html before calling it, then give us the minimal markup that can repro the issue.

Comment: How does it work for images in a document? does it calls it again.? I have images in my document.

Comment: @Kaiido, I'm able to replicate it using a minimal html. I've added a js fiddle you can check it out.

Comment: @Defyleiti, when trying with your fiddle I only have three requests to a dataURI : an empty svg document, an one pixel gif and the actual result image.